# Auto-adjust and synchronize column width in HTML Bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 HTML tables one below the other. Each table has 3 columns. The column width inside each table is currently getting auto adjusted to accommodate the longest text; this is perfectly fine.

But I would like the column widths of both the tables to be in sync (after auto adjust based on the longest text, I would like the widths of each column in both tables to be synchronized and adjusted to be the same).

how do I achieve this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Bootstrap Grid system?
This will most certainly help you out.

[Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: This looks good - but I have  2 rows containing 3 HTML tables each. And each HTML table contains a few columns. I would like the width of each column of each table in a row to be in sync with the same column in the same table in the other row. Is there a way to achieve this please?

Comment: Would you like to have your columns to have static width or a dynamic width? If you would like to have a static width, try to implement class="col" into your td's

Comment: I would like the columns to have a dynamic width please